# vue router makes multiple components?

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with the vue router seemingly creating multiple components when I navigate.
The mounted function fires every time I navigate back to a component rendered in a view.
Is this normal?
What is worse; each function in my component fires multiple times, depending on how often I navigated to the component.
It seems that the router is not reusing the component, but creates a new one at each navigation. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Are you using [`keep-alive`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive)?

Comment: Yes, keep-alive helped! :) Thank you.